# Django trouble serving media files

Tags: django

Getting back into django after a hiatus of a few months. Using 1.3. I have this url pattern:

```
(r'^(?P<path>[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}.jpg)','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':'/media/uploads'})
```

I put test.jpg in /media/uploads. I go to localhost:8000/test.jpg and the url seems to match the pattern, but I get a 404 - ""/media/uploads/test.jpg" does not exist". What could the problem be? I saw a thread where someone was having the same problem and the reason ended up being that MEDIA_URL and ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX were the same, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

`document_root` should be an absolute path.

Unless you literally have a file at `/media/uploads/test.jpg`

It's probably more like `/path-to-my-project/media/uploads/`

Comment: I agree with you on this one, always go the absolute path route